# Merge python dicts with same key in another dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Ex: Alias, Speed, Duplex:

Alias, Speed, Duplex are dicts with form {key: val} but in some cases Alias or Speed or Duplex may be null

So my problem is that if I use:

```
 dd = defaultdict(list)
        for d in (Alias, Speed, Duplex):
            for key, value in d.items():
                dd[key].append(value)
```

I will have a result with `{key: [aliasVal, speedVal, duplexVal]}` but as I already told you if Alias is null I will have `{key: [speedVal, duplexVal]}`.

So I need to replace list with dict. Final result should be:

```
{key: {"aliasVal": aliasVal, "speedVal": speedVal, "duplexVal": duplexVal }}
```

And now we know keys and value if those exists

Comment: By "null" do you mean `None`? Because in that case you'll get an `AttributeError`. Or an empty dictionary `{}`? You say you want a dictionary instead of a list, so where's your attempt to implement that? It would be straightforward to change the definition of `dd` to accommodate that, why not start there? And don't just *assert* that your question isn't a duplicate, that's no use to anybody - show your research, what have you read that you think others would consider duplicates and how precisely do they fail to answer your question?

Comment: post sample input and output , its confusing what actually you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

First i want to thank you for your help but i solved this with

```
dd = defaultdict(dict)
    for d in (Alias, Descr, Speed, Duplex, adminState, opState):
        for key, value in d.items():
            dd[key].update(value)

    for elem in dd:
        """ If key doesn't exists i will create a new format key: None for db
        """
        descr = dd[elem].get("Descr", None)
        alias = dd[elem].get("Alias", None)
        speed = dd[elem].get("Speed", None)
        duplex = dd[elem].get("Duplex", None)
```